# Запятая при встрече союзов Так что если и тире

Tags: запятая

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна запятая перед если и запятая после гражданство.

Так что если у вас есть планы, связанные с другими странами, которые потребуют второе гражданство – это рискованно.

Comment: @Aseo, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Запятая нужна, так как встречаются 2 одиночных (не двойных) союза. ТО здесь нет. Тире  ставится по правилу.

Одно из условий, благоприятствующих постановке тире в сложноподчиненном предложении, - наличие слов *это, вот*:

*Что она натура честная — это мне ясно (Т.); Когда муха назойливо вьётся перед вашими глазами — это неприятно, но когда комар ночью неустанно трубит над вашим ухом — это просто невыносимо; Что замечательно в этом лесе — это что он весь из сосен; Где он сейчас, чем занимается — вот вопросы, на которые я не мог получить ответов; А что он был умница — это вы можете мне поверить; Что он в ней нашёл — это его дело*.

Можно считать это тире интонационным, авторским или заменяющим ТО, но ТО здесь нет, а значит, запятая обязательна. Тем более что придаточное легко переставить: *Так что это рискованно, если у вас есть планы.*

Comment: ПРИМЕРЫ без запятой: "Так что если у человека есть деньги и он хочет поехать ― пожалуйста.Так что если хозяин жилья что-то обещал, но не выполняет ― тоже некрасиво.Так что если вам что-то интересно ― спрашивайте, буду рада помочь!Так что если во всем остальном он Вас устраивает ― смиритесь".

Comment: И еще одно замечание по поводу перестановок. Современная грамматика утверждает, что семантика отношений в СПП зависит от места придаточного предложения. Если главное предложение стоит впереди, то мы имеем одностороннюю зависимость придаточного от главного, при этом придаточное имеет присоединительный характер. Препозиция придаточного - это двусторонняя зависимость. Тогда для условных придаточных мы имеем или условное значение, или условно-следственное (при наличии ТО). Думаю,что в нашем случае это именно двустороннее условно-следственное значение.

Comment: О ФИКСИРОВАННОМ ПОРЯДКЕ СЛОВ. В предложениях вида "Что она натура честная — это мне ясно" перестановка вообще невозможна, а то получится: Это мне ясно, что она натура честная. Здесь фиксированный порядок слов. А откуда вообще берется "ЭТО"? Например: "Рискованно, если у вас есть такие планы". Это союзное СПП с изъяснением, опорным словом является наречие, поэтому порядок слов фиксирован. Если все-таки хотим применить инверсию, то дополнительно используется  местоимение ЭТО: "Если у вас есть такие планы - это рискованно". Порядок слов при такой структуре опять же фиксированный.

Comment: Обобщенная структура нашего предложения предложения: Так что (такой вариант) - это рискованно. После союза "так что"  "вариант" излагается в виде распространенного придаточного предложения с союзом ЕСЛИ, поэтому запятая после "так что" совершенно неуместна. Она ломает старшую структуру, важную для понимания, в угоду формальным правилам.

Comment: София, ваши аргументы мне понятны. Тем более что, если бы в начале предложения стояли И, А, НО, запятая могла бы отсутствовать по правилу. Но на другие союзы (в том числе и ТАК ЧТО) это правило пока не распространяется. А откуда ваши примеры без запятой? В справочниках по пунктуации их быть не должно. Из художественной литературы?

Answer (score 3):

Так что, если у вас есть планы, связанные с другими странами, которые потребуют второе гражданство, – это рискованно.

Главное предложение - ТАК ЧТО ЭТО РИСКОВАННО, внутри него - два придаточных через запятую, поэтому после них оставляем и запятую, завершающую придаточное, и тире, позволяющее отделить два придаточных предложения с запятой между ними от главного.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна: Так что если у вас есть планы, связанные с другими странами, которые потребуют второе гражданство, – это рискованно.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Запятая ставится на стыке союзов ТАК ЧТО, ЕСЛИ, придаточное можно переставить:  Так что, если бы он и продолжался ещё, я охотно предоставила бы моё колено для того, чтобы к нему прикладывались тысячи висельников и убийц...(М. Булгаков).

2) Запятая не ставится на стыке союзов ТАК ЧТО, ЕСЛИ...ТО, придаточное нельзя переставить: Так что если кому не интересно, то эту часть вполне можно пропустить.

3)При наличии тире запятая не ставится, так как тире фактически заменяет местоимение "ТО": Так что если вы на время отложите книгу ― автор не обидится.